# How do you use DSolve with Vector?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to create an ODE for motion in 2 dimensions.  What I have so far is:

```
x0 = {1.5, -4.}; 
v = {0, 8}; 
DSolve[{x'[t] == v, x[0] == x0}, x[t], t]
```

This works with one dimension, but when I try and expand the idea for a vector/matrix, I get:

`DSolve::nolist: List encountered within {(x^\[Prime])[t]=={0,8}}. There should be no lists on either side of the equations.`

How do I fix this?

Comment: `NDSolve` works without problems: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == {0, 8}, x[0] == {1.5, -4.}}, x , {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Yeah, I haven't quite figured out why NDSolve is smart enough to deal with a list, but DSolve can't.

Comment: Nor am I , mysterious!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MMa doesn't know `x[t]` is a vector, so try this.

```
x0 = {1.5, -4.};
v = {0, 8};
x[t_] = {x1[t], x2[t]}

eq = x'[t] == v // Thread
(*{x1'[t] == 0, x2'[t] == 8}*)

init = x[0] == x0 // Thread
(*{x1[0] == 1.5, x2[0] == -4.}*)

DSolve[{eq, init}, x[t], t]
(*{{x1[t] -> 1.5, x2[t] -> 8 t - 4.}}*)

x[t] /. %
(*{{1.5, 8 t - 4.}}*)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  The velocity equation resolves to ${Derivative[1][x][t] == 0, Derivative[1][x][t] == 8}$ and thus **DSolve** doesn't have enough dependent variables to solve.

Comment: The threading doesn't do what your comments suggest they should do.

Comment: Corrected. I had mistakenly commented out the `x[t]` equation.  Now changed the init to `x0`.  Should work for you.

Comment: You must not have the `x` array assigned.

Comment: @Quarkly it worked for me

Comment: OK.  It does work now. Thank you.